# Cicular database update on CollectionChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, database, sqlite, events

I have a real conondrum on my hands.

I'm using an `ObservableCollection` in my Model that is bound to another collection in the ViewModel. This lets me easily propagate changes in the ViewModel to the Model and vice-versa.

The objects in the Model collection are stored and retrieved from an SQLite database. I've assigned a method `UpdateDatabase()` to handle `CollectionChanged` which adds or deletes items from the database each time the collection is modified, and I added a method `GetItems()` which retrieves the database contents.

```
public class Data : Model
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> Bundle;
    private DataBase database;

    public Data(){
    {
        Bundle = database.GetItems();
        Bundle.CollectionChanged += UpdateDatabase;
    }
    private void UpdateDataBase(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            database.Delete(e.OldItems);
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            database.Insert(e.NewItems);
        }
    }
    public void Refresh()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Item> NewItems = database.GetItems();
        Bundle.Clear();
        foreach (Item item in NewItems)
        {
            Bundle.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

public class Database
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> GetItems(){...}
    public void Delete(IList items){...}
    public void Insert(IList Items){...}
    [...]
}
```

The problem is that each time I refresh my Model by querying the database and adding the retrieved items to the collection, it triggers a `CollectionChanged` and tries to insert into the database *the items I just retrieved from the database*!

However, **I still need the CollectionChanged to trigger so the ViewModel updates it's collection**.

[image: Diagram of function calls]

I'm really at loss on how to solve this. Does anybody know of a pattern that would be adequate here?

Comment: plus one just for the cool sequence diagram :)

Comment: Thanks! I always doodle diagrams when I'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a boolean flag that you set the `false` when you don't want to do something in the `CollectionChanged` event handler, e.g.:

```
public class Data : Model
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> Bundle;
    private DataBase database;

    public Data()
    {
        Bundle = database.GetItems();
        Bundle.CollectionChanged += UpdateDatabase;
    }

    private bool _doUpdate = true;
    private void UpdateDataBase(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_doUpdate)
            return;

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            database.Delete(e.OldItems);
        }
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            database.Insert(e.NewItems);
        }
    }
    public void Refresh()
    {
        _doUpdate = false; //suspend updates...
        ObservableCollection<Item> NewItems = database.GetItems();
        Bundle.Clear();
        foreach (Item item in NewItems)
        {
            Bundle.Add(item);
        }
        _doUpdate = true; //resume updates...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a actually a pretty nice solution. I'll just encapsulate the boolean state changes in `SuspendUpdates()` and `ResumeUpdates()`. Thanks a lot!